# Permanently redirect to another url in django

Tags: python, django, url, redirect, django-views

I have an application in django 1.5. I would like to do redirect from one address to another - permanently. That is, I want to get an effect in which I will redirect:

from:
`domain.com/team/event-2019/01-03-2019/827`

to:
`domain.com/team/event/01-03-2019/827` - (without 2019)

traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/team/event/01-03-2019/827

Django Version: 1.5.4
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'haystack',
 'users',
 'adminextra',
 'cms',
 'pages',
 'files',
 'south',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'home',
 'productions',
 'contact',
 'search')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'translation.middleware.LocaleMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "project/web/productions/views.py" in activity_details
  284.         return redirect(activity.get_absolute_url())
File "project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in redirect
  78.     return redirect_class(resolve_url(to, *args, **kwargs))
File "project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in resolve_url
  151.         return urlresolvers.reverse(to, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
File "project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  496.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
File "project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  381.             raise NoReverseMatch("Error importing '%s': %s." % (lookup_view, e))

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /team/event/01-03-2019/827
Exception Value: Error importing 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /team/event/01-03-2019/827

': 'HttpResponseRedirect' object has no attribute 'rindex'.
```

I would like the event to be at the address: always under this url: `domain.com/team/event/01-03-2019/827` and redirect on this url from: `domain.com/team/event-2019/01-03-2019/827`

Now I got an error:
`'HttpResponseRedirect' object has no attribute 'find'`
from this place:

```
if event_slug != activity.event.slug or str(date_url) != str(format_date(activity.date, "d-m-Y")):
    return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(activity.get_absolute_url())
```

Comment: Does the action have to be a true redirect? If not, you could just add another line to your urls.py file that sends the event-2019 URL to the same view.

Comment: It looks as if `activity.get_absolute_url()` isn't returning a URL as expected.

Comment: Please, add the full code of your redirect view.